# How to stop datagridview cursor from scrolling to the top when datasource is updated?

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

I have a datatable which is being updated every second with real time data. I do this in a Forms Timer. Now when I am scrolling down the datagridview and the datatable gets updated the cursor goes to the top of the datagridview. This is very annoying and I have tried everything that I can think of but nothing works. This is how I update the datatable,

```
private void updateDataTable()
    {
        DataRow dr;
        processTable.Clear();
        foreach (DictionaryEntry item in processSet)
        {
            ArrayList row = (ArrayList)item.Value;
            dr = processTable.NewRow();
            dr[0] = row[0].ToString();
            dr[1] = row[1].ToString();
            dr[2] = row[2].ToString();
            processTable.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Constantly replacing the grid's entire row set is probably not the best way to do this.  Keep one DataSource and add or remove the rows from it instead.

Comment: You mean like update the existing rows in the datatable with the new values?

Comment: Yes.  The DataTable would be the DataSource of the grid.  You would not add or remove rows directly on the grid then.